# Click a button from another Application, emulating mouse + coords?

Tags: c#, controls, location, mouseclick-event

I have tried to click on the button using the follow:

```
private const int BN_CLICK = 0xF5;
private const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
private const uint WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
SendMessage(sendButton, BN_CLICK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(sendButton, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(sendButton, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

All the above fail to click the button, **so I was wondering about other alternatives I have or if it is possible to get the button location X and Y from it's handler** ?

Suggestions, ideas would be really good.

Comment: Can I ask what the other program is? I too have encountered the need to click a button from another application, eg: sending emails using Outlook brings up an annoying security dialog "another program is trying to send emails..." and clicking the button programmatically looked dodgy, was unreliable and fought with the users control of the mouse. Instead I choose to buy a component that overcame the outlook dialog, is this an option to you? Otherwise you can find the answer to your question here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

Comment: @Jeremy it is a self made Lan House control that sends all messages to a debug window on the application and I am filtering those messages. For example when blocked websites are detected it gives me the option to click a button to lock the station. So I am making an application that filter those messages and if it finds some specific messages it takes action and click the button. I already went thru the msdn and several other replies in here and my problem is not emulation the mouse or keyboard but finding the location of the button do to such task, if possible completely in background.

Comment: No I don't have the source code of it and the person who developed it is no longer available at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests using sendmessage I have resolved trying PostMessage which worked like a charm...

```
PostMessage(mainControlChild, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.Return, 0);
PostMessage(mainControlChild, WM_KEYUP, (int)Keys.Return, 0);
```

Resolved my problem and sends it on background.

Answer (score 1):

If the button have hot-key (Alt+...), you can use sending message about pressing keyboard keys:

```
//Presses virtual key in active window.
void PressVK(UINT vk)
{
    //Down Alt.
    keybd_event(VK_MENU, MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU, 0), 0, 0);
    //Press key.
    keybd_event(vk, MapVirtualKey(vk, 0), 0, 0);
    keybd_event(vk, MapVirtualKey(vk, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
    //Up Alt.
    keybd_event(VK_MENU, MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}
```

It's a C++ code. But you can import all that functions to C# and use them. All what you need: activate target window and call this function with correct key as parameter.

If you have handle of the button then call `GetWindowRect`. It will return a pointer to a `RECT` structure that receives the screen coordinates of the upper-left and lower-right corners of the window. So you will be able to perform click emulation regardless main windows size.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

Using it:

```
RECT rect;
if (!GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), out rect))
{
    //Error.
}
```

Comment: @archer thanks for the ideia but there is no hotkey connected to it :/ I also tried sending enter but if it is not selected doesnt work either. Sad part is that ALL the other controls works just fine with BN_CLICK but this one.

Comment: @Prix, how about to send few times TAB and select button before sending ENTER?

Comment: @archer and how would I know that the button is actually selected ? there is a lot of controls that I belive the tab would go thru. Also using Controls.FromHandler doesnt work for me it is always null even while my findwindowex can hook it just fine.

Comment: @Prix, try to do it yourself and count... I don't know what actually are you doing and what program works with, so can only gives ideas. Also, if you have button handle (as I see in example), have you tried to send to it ENTER using WM_KEYDOWN message?

Comment: @archer yes I have tried sending enter to it as well. Well I am all new to finding and using others app window controls and I am currently using Spy++ to find all the stuff I need to use but I dont see anything to tell me wether I have a button selected or not if I could get the buttons location from the handler for instance, I could perform a mouse click emulation to the location but I am not sure on how to get that from the button child of the handler and since chaning the window size would mess it up would need a location from the handler child to be more accurated.

Comment: @Prix, you can find actual coordinates of button from its handle using `GetWindowRect` function.

Comment: @archer I tried it a few times by sending the button handle to it and I always got 0 from it, while it worked with FindWindow from the main window handle which doesnt help in my case.

Comment: @Prix, if the function returns 0 then it fails. Retrieve error info using `GetLastError`. Probably something wrong with how you import function and `RECT` structure to managed code. Added code to my answer.

Comment: @archer that was what I was using from pinvoke and yes it returned 0. I will test again to try to get the last error and will update once I do thanks for the idea.